# Laptop won't boot and charger won't work

Tags: boot, laptop, power

Last night when I went to shut down my laptop, only the "install updates then shutdown" option was available and the usual "shut down" option wasn't there.

I decided to just go ahead and choose it, but because the "configuration screen" was taking too long, and the instruction said not to turn off the computer, I plugged in my laptop's charger (because the battery was low) and let it do whatever it had to do.

This morning, the "light" showed that it was fully charged so I unplugged the charger. Later, when I tried to turn it on, it wouldn't. Nothing happened. No "power on light" and no sound either. And when I tried plugging in the charger, the "charging light" didn't appear anymore.

Thinking the charger was the source of the problem I bought a new charger for it. But even with the new charger, the "charging light" still won't show up.

I have all my documents saved on it and now I can't turn them in tomorrow. I don't understand why it was working fine last night but this morning it will no longer boot and the charger doesn't work.

The battery is non-removable and its a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

From what are you saying, it's safe to say that your Laptop's motherboard has shorted out.

You can do nothing about this but ask for a warranty to the Laptop manufacturer.

There is a chance that the laptop short-circuited and destroyed your hard disk, but it's less likely.

But if you really need to get your data back, you can remove your hard disk out of your computer and back up / take the data from another computer. Then you can use the data as you please until your laptop is fixed.